# PHPUnit code coverage in PhpStorm does not bootstrap Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, phpstorm

I'm having a strange problem on Laravel 5.5. I'm using PhpStorm and am trying to use it to make a `phpunit` call on my Vagrant host to PHPUnit like this:

> vagrant:///Users/mymachine/Webdev/project/usr/bin/php
>   -dxdebug.coverage_enable=1 /home/vagrant/project/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit --coverage-clover
>   /home/vagrant/.phpstorm_helpers/project_AdminLoginTest_coverage
>   --bootstrap /home/vagrant/project/bootstrap/app.php --configuration /home/vagrant/project/phpunit.xml
>   Tests\Integration\Authentication\AdminLoginTest
>   /home/vagrant/project/tests/Integration/Authentication/AdminLoginTest.php
>   --teamcity

I've defined my default configuration file to be the `phpunit.xml` file that comes with Laravel by default, and running tests normally *without coverage* works just fine. It's whenever I try to make use of code coverage that it starts failing with the following error:

> Uncaught Error: Class 'Route' not found in /home/vagrant/project/app/routes.php:5

The reason for this is because it's not loading the Facade properly and is likely not even booting Laravel.

Has anyone got this to work before? If so how?

I am using a `setUp()` call, it's defined as such

```
protected function setUp()
{
    parent::setUp(); // Must run first, Laravel is set up using this parent call //
    /** @var AdminModel $user */
    $this->user = $this->createAdmin();
}
```

I do run `setUp()` from the parent first as that is supposed to call `createApplication()` which **should** take care of booting Laravel if I'm not mistaken.

I've set up **Xdebug** on my Vagrant machine on both FPM and CLI as well, and PhpStorm successfully reports that it can detect `Xdebug 2.5.5` on my Vagrant box via *CLI*, so I'm ruling that out as a possibility unless I need to install something extra for the Coverage.

My `phpunit.xml` also sets up the `bootstrap/app.php` file in it's bootstrap definition, which is the Laravel default, so that should work fine and the fact that it works **without the coverage** confuses me.

Am I missing something here? Thank you for your help. Let me know if I'm missing some details you need.

Answer (score 0):

After much trial and error i figured it out, so, the problem is that my PHPUnit code coverage in this case is including the `routes.php` and PHPUnit's XDebug used for the code coverage feature fails to understand the Facade usage in this file *(guess it's booted too early? would appreciate clarification if anyone knows why this is)*

Note that this is only an issue because i have a **custom** routes.php file inside my `App` directory, the way to make this work is to just tell PHPUnit to exclude this specific routes file from the **Whitelist** that Laravel defines.

```
<filter>
    <whitelist processUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
        <directory suffix=".php">./app/API</directory>
        <exclude>
            <file>./app/API/routes.php</file>
        </exclude>
    </whitelist>
</filter>
```

For me it looks like that, after you exclude that file the Code Coverage should work fine provided that you have XDebug installed, the other Facades are loaded just fine, so i'm guessing the one in `routes.php` doesn't because that's loaded earlier in the lifecycle of Laravel.

Hope this helps someone in the future :)